# Can I OR geo search with numeric filters?

Tags: algolia

I am using insideBoundingBox, and I would like to add a numeric filter. 
Something like

```
color_id=12 OR insideBoundingBox='...'
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not supported by the Algolia API. The work-around would be to perform 2 queries and merge the results sets.

Maybe you could first display the results matching "in the area" followed by the ones that are matching the `color_id`?